# Is a stretched out torus still a $C^\infty$ manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, compact-manifolds

Suppose you have a torus and you carefully make a cylindrical cut down the center. Then you stretch out the outer half and glue together annular regions of the plane in the empty space. Now you have a torus that has a flat top and bottom
[image: Flattened Torus]

Is this still a $C^\infty$ manifold? Or did we mess it up and it's merely a topological manifold. I ask because the curvature is discontinuous (it is zero on the flat parts and non-zero on the curvy parts).

In a lower dimension, this question still bothers me: This is a stretched out circle (I'll include the parametric functions to make it painfully obvious, how I got this shape):

[image: stretched out circle]

Can someone please tell me the nature of these manifolds? Also (bonus:) If we've lost the $C^\infty$-ness by this construction, how can we maintain it? What is a smoothing procedure for, say, taking the strecthed out circle above and making it $C^\infty$ by somehow fixing the connecting points?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, here you have a $C^1$ manifold that is not $C^2$. It is not hard to give it an intrinsic structure as a $C^\infty$ manifold, but its embedding in 3-dimensional space will still only be $C^1$, as the curvature jumps suddenly from a positive constant to zero. As for smoothing it out, it shouldn't be too hard with the help of some smooth function that vanishes for $x\le0$, yet is positive for $x>0$. Maybe someone will come up with a concrete suggestion.

Comment: OK, well I appreciate the comment.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen You did answer the question of the nature of the manifolds. If you Answerify your comment. I'll accept it.

Comment: Okay, I had a little more time to spare so I added one concrete suggestion for making the flattened torus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a $C^1$ manifold that is not $C^2$. It is not hard to give it an intrinsic structure as a $C^∞$ manifold, but its embedding in 3-dimensional space will still only be $C^1$, as the curvature jumps suddenly from a positive constant to zero.

For the flattening out, here is one way to do it: Pick a $C^∞$ function $\psi$ so that $\psi(x)=0$ for $0\le x≤\frac12$ in a neigbourhood of $0$, and $\psi(x)=x-1$ for $x≥\frac32$, and consider the graph
$$\bigl\{\,(x,\sqrt{1-\psi(x)^2})\colon 0\le x\le2\,\bigr\}.$$
This is smooth; it is flat for $0≤x≤\frac12$, and the part with $x≥\frac32$ is a circular arc. Now join this with its mirror images through the axis, and you have a smooth flattened curve. Rotate it around the $y$ axis to get a smooth flattened torus.